# deferReply() cannot solve DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction

Tags: javascript, async-await, discord, discord.js, bots

I am trying to make a discord bot with discordJS (v14) and I followed the tutorial from
https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/slash-commands.html#individual-command-files and created a slash command. However, when I call the slash command, it always shoe `DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction` I tried to use the command `await interaction.deferReply()`  but it still failed.

Here are my code of that function

### play.js

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName("play")
        .setDescription("Play the song from the url or search query")
        .addStringOption(option =>
            option.setName("query")
                .setDescription("The url or search query")
                .setRequired(true)
        ),

    async execute(interaction) {
        console.log("interaction received"); // This part can run
        await interaction.deferReply() 
        console.log("play command executed"); // cannot run
        await interaction.editReply({ content: interaction.options.getString("query"), ephemeral: true });

    }
}
```

### index.js

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const {
    Client,
    Collection,
    Events,
    GatewayIntentBits,
    REST,
    Routes,
} = require('discord.js');
require("dotenv").config();

// Tokens
const BOT_TOKEN = process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN;
const CLIENT_ID = process.env.CLIENT_ID;

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
const rest = new REST({ version: 10 }).setToken(BOT_TOKEN);

// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
// We use 'c' for the event parameter to keep it separate from the already defined 'client'
client.once(Events.ClientReady, c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

// Create a new collection for commands
client.commands = new Collection();
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
    if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
        client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
    } else {
        console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
    }
}

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;
    console.log(interaction);

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }
    console.log(`Executing ${interaction.commandName} command.`);
    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

const commands = [];

// Grab the SlashCommandBuilder#toJSON() output of each command's data for deployment
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    console.log(command.data.toJSON());
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

// try to register the slash commands
(async () => {
    try {
        console.log(`Started refreshing ${commands.length} application (/) commands.`);

        // The put method is used to fully refresh all commands in the guild with the current set
        const data = await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationCommands(CLIENT_ID),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log(`Successfully reloaded ${data.length} application (/) commands.`);
        
        // Log in to Discord with your client's token
        client.login(BOT_TOKEN);
    } catch (error) {
        // And of course, make sure you catch and log any errors!
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

The terminal result shows that it received the message but it continue to have the error
`DiscordAPIError[10062]: Unknown interaction`

May I ask how can I solve the problem and why it would happen?

Comment: Try not awaiting interaction.deferReply(); In my bot, I do not await that.